# using an array index as a counter in a loop to sum its values

Tags: java, arrays, oop

In

```
array[0]=7
array[1]=3
array[2]=6
array[3]=1
```

I would like to use the array index as a counter in a loop and sum the values of the array

ex. counter starts at index 2, return 7. 6+1

or

counter starts at index 1 and returns 10. 3+6+1

```
public class ar {

    static int[] a = new int[8];

    {
        a[0]= 6;
        a[1]= 5;
        a[2]= 34;
        a[3]= 53;
        a[4]= 2;
        a[5]= 7;
        a[6]= 31;
        a[7]= 60;
    }

    static int b(int num){
        int c = 0;

        for(int i = a[num]; i<a.length; i++) {
            c = c + a[num];
        }
        return c;   
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(b(2));
    }
}
```

its returning 0 at any index. I think I am mixing the index and value incorrectly at

```
int i = a[num]
```

and at

```
c = c + a[num];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just a minor change:

```
static int b(int num){
     int sum = 0;
     for (int index = num; index < a.length; index++) {
        sum = sum + a[index];
     }
     return sum;
}
```

You were starting from the wrong index and not accessing the correct elements (not using `i`).

And you need to prepend the `static` keyword to your initializer. Otherwise the code would only be executed if you create an instance of the class, not for the static one.

```
static {
    a[0]= 6;
    a[1]= 5;
    a[2]= 34;
    a[3]= 53;
    a[4]= 2;
    a[5]= 7;
    a[6]= 31;
    a[7]= 60;
}
```

*Note:* try to assign names for variables that represent their functionality. It will help make your code more readable. In this example it was pretty obvious what you intended to do, but in more complex ones it will get messy without.

Answer (score 1):

try inside your `b` method:

```
int c=0;
for(int i=num; i<a.length;i++){
    c = c + a[i];}
return c;
```